# Is there an easy way to parse all sent over one stream traffic via the tcp protocol in wireshark?

Tags: tcp, download, wireshark, file-transfer

I have a pcap file. In one moment one computer started sending an elf file to another using tcp protocol. I want to download this file, but I don't know understand how to unite all separated packages into one file.
[sending the elf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK2zy.png)

I tried to the function of wireshark "Follow the TCP stream" but there are something about 3000 packages. It takes 5 minutes to load only 1000 packages. More loaded packages, less speed of loading new ones.